# Coldfusion cfmail tag not sending emails that are using the same domain

Tags: email, coldfusion, web-hosting, cfmail

so I used the cfmail tag to send the information from a form to specific emails, and the tag works perfectly for my personal email at outlook.com and etc. But when I have it set to the email that I use for that domain and that site. It doesn't ever get sent, and there's no issues that I see, and I'm not necessarily sure if that's a hosing issue, or how to even take care of that.
Any suggestions?

Comment: To receive a constructive answer, you should post your code.

Comment: In addition to @Fergus response - you'll definitely want to start logging sent mail in the CFadmin and report any errors or discrepancies here as well.

Comment: Talk to your mail-meisters.  Maybe it's getting spam trapped.

Comment: The mail server for the email that you are sending to might need to white list the IP of the server that is sending the email. Depends on the rules set there. Many times organizations add specific rules for their networks.